# HomePod 1st + 2nd gen

Tags: homepod

I get you can’t pair them for stereo, fine. But can they simply be mixed in the same Mac / Siri network? I want to put my 1st gen upstairs, add a 2nd gen down - as the hub - and still have it all mostly work.

Comment: You should be able to have both generations on the same network.  Can you expand/clarify what you mean by "have it all mostly work"?  Is it not working, are they connected but not working properly, or something else?

Comment: @Ezekiel answered it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can mix any AirPlay devices in the same network and play simultaneously to them. You just can't make stereo pairs, as you note.

For example, you could stream to a HomePod mini, HomePod (1st gen), HomePod (2nd gen), and a Sonos device simultaneously using AirPlay.

Your Home hub will also automatically self-select, you don't have to do anything for that to work.